# Stereo recording using 2 external mic?

Tags: android

I am new to android development. I am trying to record an audio file in stereo mode. I have connected two external mics using 3.5mm jack.

[image: Wiring diagram]

The only problem is that my recording is done in mono mode. Both speakers sounds same. I am using inbuilt recorder app in my phone. Is stereo recording possible in smartphones using external mic? If so, do I need to code for stereo recording? And what libraries should I use?

Answer (score 1):

Speak two different words, one to each microphone and try to figure out if both speakers are getting a "blend" of both sides or if you're only getting one of the mics, then post the results to get a more accurate answer.

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20634477/audio-recording-in-stereo-giving-same-data-in-left-and-right-channels) where the topic is discussed, maybe it has to do with the configuration in your source code.

Comment: Yes my both mics are working properly. But the jack is taking both input as single one. The recorder cannot distinguish between two different mics. For checking should i use the default app in android phone or should i code for new one ?